# Search text in multiple Excel (xls) files in Linux

Tags: linux, microsoft-excel

I'm using Ubuntu Linux and I can't find a way to find a text in multiple excel (`xls`) files. My desire is do this by command line, but other alternatives are welcome too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made one using ssconvert tool (from Gnumeric). You need to install the Gnumeric first:

```
sudo apt-get install gnumeric
```

You can save the content as script and call:

```
./script-find-in-xls.sh text
```

The content of the script.

```
#!/bin/sh

# $1 - text to find

if [ -z "$1" ]
  then
    echo 'Please, the text is mandatory'
    exit 1
fi

rm -rf /tmp/xls-csv/
mkdir /tmp/xls-csv/

cd /tmp/xls-csv/
cp /location/of/excel-files/*.xls /tmp/xls-csv/

for f in *.xls; do
    ssconvert -S --import-encoding=ISO8859-1 ./"$f" ./"${f%.xls}.csv"
done

cat *.csv.* > all-xls-content.txt
rm *.csv.*

if cat all-xls-content.txt | egrep --color $1; then
    echo 'found'
else
    echo 'not found'
fi
```

The script convert all xls files in csv files, join the csv files in a single one file and use the `egrep` to find the text.

The code it's not perfect, but do the job.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. Run this script:

```
python search.py /home/user/directory string
```

Here you find my solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os, sys
import xlrd

def find(path, word):

    l = []

    d = os.listdir(path)

    for file in d:

        filename = str(path) +'/' + str(file)

        print ('Finding in %s' %file)

        if filename.endswith('.xlsx'):

            wb = xlrd.open_workbook(filename)
            ws = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

            for i, row in enumerate(range(ws.nrows)):
                for j, col in enumerate(range(ws.ncols)):
                    if str(word) in str(ws.cell_value(i, j)):
                        l.append((file,row,col))
    if l:
        print ('Word %s found %d times in:' %(word,len(l)))

        for fn, row, col in l:
            print ('File: %s, row: %s ,column: %s' %(fn,row,col))        
    else:
        print ('Word %s not found' %word) 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        find (sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2])
    except IndexError:
        print('\tExecute: python searchpy <path> <word>')
        print('\tEg: python searchpy /home/user/files/ Fox')
```

You can pull from Github: [searb-in-xlsx](https://github.com/Superbuy-Team/search-in-xlsx)

Answer (score 2):

If you are ok with installing an indexing application, it could be an answer.

I personnaly use [recoll](http://www.recoll.org/), wich is easy to setup and install. Its defaults interface is a GUI, but it is also possible to use it in CLI:

`recoll -q <search terms>`

You can setup a scheduled task to update its index, or launch it manually with `recollindex` (in both cases you can restrict the index to the path of your choices).

Answer (score 2):

Modifying Andre Araujo's answer to use openpyxl because xlrd can no longer open xslx files:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

import os, sys
import openpyxl


def find(path, word):

    l = []

    d = os.listdir(path)

    for file in d:

        filename = str(path) + "/" + str(file)

        print("Finding %s in %s" % (word, file))

        if filename.endswith(".xlsx"):

            wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=filename)
            ws = wb.active

            for row in ws.rows:
                for cell in row:
                    if cell.value and str(word) in cell.value:
                        l.append((file, cell))
    if l:
        print("Word %s found %d times in:" % (word, len(l)))

        for fn, cell in l:
            print("File: %s, row: %s ,column: %s" % (fn, cell.row, cell.column))
    else:
        print("Word %s not found" % word)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        find(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
    except IndexError:
        print("\tExecute: python searchpy <path> <word>")
        print("\tEg: python searchpy /home/user/files/ Fox")
```